# On-event cannot get the object from the Gridlayout ,in nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

my js code

```
var gridLayout = page.getViewById("grid9");
var num;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        num = i * 3 + j;
        //build the grids
        var cell = new StackLayout();
        cell.id = "GD" + num;
        cell.className = "grid";
        cell.on("tap", function () {
            alert(this.id);//  <============problem is here!
        });


        var img = new ImageModule.Image();
        img.src = "~/img/u.png";
        cell.addChild(img);

        GridLayout.setRow(cell, i);
        GridLayout.setColumn(cell, j);
        gridLayout.addChild(cell);
    }
}
```

The app shows me the right 9 pictures,but alert me `undefined` when I touch every gird.
After change the alert method param `this.id` to `cell.id`,it shows `GD8` if I tap the grids-every grid.
It looks like I haven't get the cell object as I tap the grid,or,it didn't exist the objetcs on page after the loaded method executing.
Am I use the on-event method in a wrong way or I falling in a JS trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `args` param to the function so that it will recognize what object that you just tapped, based on that print out the id of that object:

```
cell.on("tap", function(args) {
    alert(args.object.id);
});
```